# Absolutely positioned child of fixed position element doesn't scroll

Tags: html, css

So I've got a fixed position element.  It has a child that is position:static.  A child of the position:static element is position:fixed, and doesn't scroll with it's parent, behaving like a fixed position element.  Is there any way to get the grandchild element to scroll?  I'd REALLY like to avoid specifying position:relative.  Any thoughts on a solution.  I'd also like to understand that behavior a little better.

```
<div class="fixed-parent">
<div>
    <div class="absolute-child">
        Test
    </div>
    <div class="some-stuff-to-make-it-tall">
        really tall
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.fixed-parent{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.fixed-parent > div{
    height:500px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
.some-stuff-to-make-it-tall{
    margin-top:25px;
    height:600px;
}
.absolute-child{
    position:absolute;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L5hscgu5/1/

Comment: I'm not clear on which element you want to scroll? Do you want the "really tall" or "test" to scroll? Adding in overflow: scroll to .absolute-child to your fiddle makes it scroll, but I don't think that's what you're asking.. https://jsfiddle.net/L5hscgu5/3/

Comment: I want test to scroll WITH it's parent, so that when you scroll the parent, .absolute-child moves.

Comment: I'm only able to create that behavior by making it's position relative, which you said you'd rather not do.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that.  Back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

Right now `.absolute-child` is not positioned relative to the scrolling div.  Adding `position: relative;` to `.fixed-parent > div` accomplishes what I think you're trying to do.

https://jsfiddle.net/L5hscgu5/4/

```
.fixed-parent > div{
    height:500px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    position: relative;
}
```